# If $m$ is a divisor of $|G|$, then $G$ contains an element of order $m$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

> If $G$ is a finite group and $m$ is a divisor of $|G|$, then $G$ contains an element of order $m$.

I know this is false, but why? Am I supposed to use Lagrange's theorem?

Comment: You can just find a counter example to prove this claim false. Try $S_3$ with $m=6$.

Comment: Or $G = \{0\}$, no?

Comment: @IvoTerek actually, no.

Comment: Oh, you're right. I made a confusion here.

Answer (score 5):

This would imply that any finite group is cyclic, since we can choose $m=|G|$.

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z \oplus \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ has size 4 but no element of order 4.